Syncfusion sparkline chart is disappearing after loading or entry soo quickly
After importing all syncfusion needs successfully to display charts I find out a bug that the chart is quickly disappearing, so after reloading the page the chart displayed for a short amount of time and then disappear again
I hope someone might have faced the same bug and can support me to handle it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
